# How do gamboostLSS and gamlss packages predict outside range of x?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, gamlss, extrapolation

The `mgcv` package performs a linear extrapolation when the `newdat` argument of the `predict` function contains values outside the range of the training covariates. I am unable to find out what happens in this use case for the `gamboostLSS` package and the `gamlss` and `mboost` packages on which it is based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this issue an to let others know [I wasn't aware of this open question]:

We had an email exchange in 2015 and decided to use linear extrapolation for smooth effects (both, P-splines and constraint P-splines). This was implemented in mboost 2.5-0. See `news(Version >= "2.5-0", package = "mboost")` and `package?mboost` for more details.